# Accessing data from an address

Tags: c

I have a struct `meta`, one of which I insert at the start of my malloc:

```
void *ptr = malloc(sizeof(meta) + sz);
struct meta meta1;
meta1.size = sz;

//Which is better?
//memmove(ptr, &meta, sizeof(meta));
//ptr = meta;
```

Later on, I want to access my meta struct. I have tried doing:

```
*((struct meta*) (ptr - sizeof(m61_meta))).size;
```

Which, moves back the address to the 'start' of the malloc, casts the pointer to be a meta pointer, then gets size. However, I'm having a compile time error, saying that it is not a struct.

Why am I receiving this error, and if you know of a better way of doing this, that would be great.

EDIT: I am trying to put 'metadata' in my pointers. So basically:

```
  memory 
[meta|data]
A    B
```

Where memory is just one malloc. I keep the pointer of data (B) and later on, I try and access the 'meta' of my data. That is,

```
(ptr - sizeof(m61_meta))
```

Which is the start of my `memory` block. I want to access my meta from here. Unfortunately, casting my `A` pointer to a `struct meta` pointer fails.

Comment: `struct meta *p = malloc(sizeof(*p) + sz); p->size = sz;` and cut out the middle man, would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting the compiler error is that the `.` operator binds more tightly than the `*` operator, so when you write

```
*((struct meta*) (ptr - sizeof(m61_meta))).size;
```

You're trying to take the `size` member of a pointer.  You probably mean

```
(*((struct meta*) (ptr - sizeof(m61_meta)))).size;
```

After that, I have no clue what your code is trying to do, but we'll deal with one bug at a time.  It's almost certainly a mistake to do `ptr - sizeof(...`, because pointer arithmetic is already scaled by the size of what's pointed to, so you'll end up skipping over a whole bunch of structures, not just one.  Second, you've allocated space for a structure, but not copied anything into it. I'm sure there are more problems.

Comment: But isn't my pointer void at that point, so I need to do -sizeof(... ? or would this be safer I just ((struct meta*) (ptr) - 1), so I move one knowing its a stuct meta pointer. I am using memmove to copy to my memory block. Haha, sorry I have limited experience with C. Also, *facepalm* on me for the dot thing.

Comment: If it were void, arithmetic wouldn't be allowed at all. You have to cast a pointer to a complete type, then you can add to it, and only then if the values are all from the same `malloc` or same array.